# How to make a call on web socket from Jmeter and send a payload

Tags: jmeter

In my test step I required to first create the connection through the web socket with the following command and after that I need to send the payload:

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:8403/connect
```

Payload which need to be tested:

```
{"type": "subscribe", "namespace": "Single Session"}
```

Working on CMD:
[image]

How to do it in JMeter ? Shall I use a websocket sampler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter out of the box doesn't support [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), you will need a plugin, i.e. [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))

Example setup:

[image]

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)

Comment: Which websocket sampler I need to install ?